# Firebase and Chart.js - Data pulled from database into array not displaying in graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js

I'm writing code to read in values from my Firebase database, store them into an array, and then plug my array into the Chart.js code to display my data in the graph. But my graph is coming up empty.

First, I create a snapshot of the values in the database, and push them to the new array `genderData`. I then confirmed that the array was populated with a `console.log(genderData)` (see below). As far as I can tell, the array was populated:

My console log: 
[image]

I then console logged outside of my ref call to the database, and it looks like this:

[image]

My code to pull data from the database:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('counters');

// Get counter values.
var genderData = [];

rootRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    genderData.push(snapshot.val()['Male']);
    genderData.push(snapshot.val()['Female']);
    genderData.push(snapshot.val()['Nonbinary']);
    genderData.push(snapshot.val()['Other']);
    genderData.push(snapshot.val()["Didn't Say"]);
    console.log(genderData);
})
console.log(genderData);
```

Then, I created a regular bar graph with Chart.js, and tried to plug in `genderData` into the graph:

```
// Bar graph displaying the total number of students by gender.
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart4").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Male", "Female", "Non-Binary", "Other", "Unspecified"],
        datasets: [{
            data: genderData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Total Students by Time Taken to Complete Degree'
        },
        legend:{
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

But my graph is empty:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Upon further inspection, I noticed that the values are showing up... kind of.

[image]

So it seems that my data just isn't creating the "bar" of the graph? And my y values start at 0.0 and end at 1.0, and I have no idea why.

Comment: The code seems to be right, I feel that the logged array looks strange, it has an additional chart_js value in it. A simple array if logged should look like this -> https://ibb.co/cUQeqV

Comment: I console logged outside of my call to the database, and updated my post with that log.